# What is the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}_2[x,y]/(x+y)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Okay, so $\mathbb{Z}_2[x,y]/(x)\cong\mathbb{Z}_2[y]$, that much I see. But what is $\mathbb{Z}_2[x,y]/(x+y)$? I think this should also be a polynomial ring in one variable, is that true? Please help, it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 3):

Forget about $\mathbb Z_2$: given a completely arbitrary commutative ring $A$ we have an isomorphism $$A[x,y]/\langle x+y \rangle\stackrel \cong \to A[x]:x\mapsto x, y\mapsto-x$$

Comment: How does it feel not to be driven crazy any more?  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Because of characteristic $2$, the polynomials $x+y=x-y$ coincide, hence the quotient is given by $$\mathbb{Z}_2[x,y]/(x+y)=\mathbb{Z}_2[x,y]/(x-y)\simeq \mathbb{Z}_2[x].$$
The idea is that we identity $x$ with $y$ in the quotient, but this can be made precise, of course. Also, as George noted, it does not depend on characteristic $2$, because we also can identity $y$ with $-x$ in general.